# In Azure Logic Apps ARM template, what are the possible values for the AuthType property for a SQL Server connector using On-Premise Data Gateway?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I have an Azure Logic App with a SQL Server connector through a On-Premise Data Gateway, the connection is made using SQL Server Authentication. It works fine from the Logic App Designer.

[image]

No details about the connection are stored in the ARM template of the SQL Server connection, so if I want to automate the deployment of the Logic App, I need to add some values to the ARM template. The documentation for this is really poor, even though I was able to write this template:

```
{
  "type": "MICROSOFT.WEB/CONNECTIONS",
  "apiVersion": "2018-07-01-preview",
  "name": "[parameters('sql_2_Connection_Name')]",
  "location": "[parameters('logicAppLocation')]",
  "properties": {
    "api": {
      "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('logicAppLocation'), '/managedApis/', 'sql')]"
    },
    "displayName": "[parameters('sql_2_Connection_DisplayName')]",
    "parameterValues": {
      "server": "[parameters('sql_2_server')]",
      "database": "[parameters('sql_2_database')]",
      "username": "[parameters('sql_2_username')]",
      "password": "[parameters('sql_2_password')]",
      "authType": "[parameters('sql_2_authtype')]",
      "sqlConnectionString": "[parameters('sql_2_sqlConnectionString')]",
      "gateway": {
        "id": "[concat('subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('dataGatewayResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/connectionGateways/', parameters('dataGatewayName'))]"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I can't find the correct value for the `authType` property corresponding to "SQL Server Authentication". The values `windows` and `basic` are accepted, but couldn't find the value for "SQL Server Authentication".

**Can someone please tell me what's the value for the `authType` property corresponding to "SQL Server Authentication"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following properties json inside your web api connection

```html
"properties": {
    "api": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/<YourSubscriptionIDHere>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/australiaeast/managedApis/sql"
    },
    "parameterValueSet": {
      "name": "sqlAuthentication",
      "values": {
        "server": {
          "value": "SampleServer"
        },
        "database": {
          "value": "WideWorldImporters"
        },
        "username": {
          "value": "sampleuser"
        },
        "password": {
          "value": "somepasssword"
        },
        "gateway": {
          "value": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionIDGoesHere>/resourceGroups/az-integration-study-rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/connectionGateways/<NameofTheGatewayHere>"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "location": "australiaeast"
```

That should do the trick